# PHP OOP while loop

Tags: php, mysql, oop

i had a problem with looping data from mysql using OOP style.

so, here is my code:

```
class mysql {

private $host;
private $username;
private $password;
private $database;
public $con;

    public function connect($setHost, $setUsername, $setPassword, $setDatabase) {

        $this->host = $setHost;
        $this->username = $setUsername;
        $this->password = $setPassword;
        $this->database = $setDatabase;

        $this->con = mysqli_connect($setHost, $setUsername, $setPassword, $setDatabase);            
    }

    public function query($setQuery) {

        $query = mysqli_query($this->con, $setQuery);

        return $query;      
    }

    public function fetch($setFetch) {

        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query($setFetch));

        return $fetch;  
    }
}


$objMysql = new mysql();
$con = $objMysql->connect("localhost" , "root" , "root" , "test");

while ($dataSlideshow = $objMysql->fetch("SELECT * FROM slideshow)) {
<h1><?php echo $dataSlideshow['images']; ?></h1>
}
```

the problem was, when i refreshing the page, it excutes without limited in the page, i dont know why, but, in mysql table, it contains only three slideshow? so, my computer got hang, and force to close the browsers. what's wrong with my code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your function definition , your code would be

```
$rs=$objMysql->query("SELECT * FROM slideshow");
while ($dataSlideshow = $objMysql->fetch($rs)) {
<h1><?php echo $dataSlideshow['images']; ?></h1>
}
```

And replace this function definition

```
 public function fetch($rs) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);

        return $row;  
    }
```

Comment: still not working Mr.Rohit, is it possible that my class has wrong/bad code?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do

```
$fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query($setFetch));
```

function `$this->query` runs and executes a query. So it will never stops.
Even if you pass `$rs` to `fetch` function - `fetch` will still brings you one result always.

So, i think you should iterate through results without function `fetch`:

```
$objMysql = new mysql();
$con = $objMysql->connect("localhost" , "root" , "root" , "test");

while ($dataSlideshow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($objMysql->query("SELECT * FROM slideshow"))) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: this one cause infinite loop, but, i appreciate  ur answer. thank you so much Mr. U_minder!